# Analyzing graphs in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I have a Django based backend where there are many users (Users 1, 2, 3 ... 100). For each user X, I can get a list of users (A, B, C) who are friends with that user on Facebook (I can find using Facebook API), and friends with that user on my database (my own custom Friendship model has this information)

I want a good way to analyze the "interconnectedness" on a daily basis, maybe in the django admin panel or somewhere else - by drawing me the 100 users and showing clusters of users who are friends with each other (on Facebook, on my database)

Is there a package that readily enables me to do this in Django, or in another platform (I can export the Django data in a compatible way and feed into this other system)

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for the logic of this computation or how to show the comparison/incorerectedness

Answer (score 0):

What about [Django Google Charts](https://github.com/jacobian-archive/django-googlecharts) or [Django Chartit](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/)?

Or for more complex you can use free [D3](http://d3js.org/) JS library.